# Upgrade Azure virtual machine to A8

Tags: azure

We have a running Azure virtual machine on A7 package but wish to upgrade it to A8 can provide steps to complete this

Comment: Please write questions as questions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to the Azure Portal, Configuration -> Settings -> Virtual Machine Size ( Pick A8 ). Click Save at the bottom and your instance would reboot.